# Postgresql data to highchart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, highcharts

I'm trying to create a simple bar chart using data stored at postgresql db with the code below. The axis of the chart appears but the data don't show up.
When I access the http://127.0.0.1:3000/test.json the data shows in this format:

*[{"value":4.0},{"value":1.0},{"value":4.0},{"value":2.0},{"value":2.0},{"value":3.0},{"value":2.0}]*

So I'm trying to change this format to [],[],[] and then use it with highchart. But I it seems that $.getJSON and my loop for (i=0.... aren't working.

```
<div id="orders_chart" style="width:560px; height:300px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function () {
var test = [];
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:3000/test.json', function(data) {
  for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    test.push([data[i].key, data[i].value]);
  }
  $('#orders_chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: "column"
    },
    title: {
      text: "Orders by Day"
    },
    series: [{
      data: test
    }]
  });
});
```

If anyone has any idea how to fix it or another approach to use highcharts with postgres database (stored from csv uploaded files) will help me alot!

Comment: You should resolve this problem server-side and send correct data to a client-side. If you data point format is `{"value":4.0}`, then why are you trying to access `key` in `data[i].key`? `test.push(data[i].value);` should work. How is `test` array looking just before using it in Highcharts?

Answer (score 0):

In ruby you can create `test` as

```
def user_dataset(data)
  data.map do |key, value|
    {
       key[:value]
    }
  end
end
```

which will return you data in [4.0, 1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0]

As per example of barchart implementation for highcharts
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/)
you need data in format

```
series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
    }]
```

for your case data is test and you can put value in place of name

Comment: I tried but it doens't work. I added the user_dataset method to test_controller.rb and defined data: user_dataset(data) in highcharts code.